# Teradata Row size Error

Tags: teradata

When I query Teradata for a specific table in bteq , I get the following error. 
How to query this table in BTEQ or any other TD SQL Client using JDBC or ODBC.

```
 *** Failure 9804 Response Row size or Constant Row size overflow.
                Statement# 1, Info =0 
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work. do this before `.logon` i.e. before establishing the session with TD.

```
.set session charset 'ascii';
```

For ODBC and JDBC clients the connection parameter called `CHARSET` should be used to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain what makes this method work? I can see that this has helped OP, but I'd like to know how changing the charset helps.

Comment: @PriyankGupta session character set is the encoding used to transfer the data from the database server to client application. since UTF8 is a variable length encoding.. I presume that the encoded row data exceeds the maximum row size of 64Kb. If the encoding is ascii, we dont run into this issue but we could potentially lose non-ascii data ..

Answer (score 1):

My Teradata Studio already uses charset and I still get this error, so I have taken extra steps to look into the column length as a root cause of this issue.

After you reduce the column size, such as cast a large column size to Varchar(100), for instance, this error will go away.

Remedy:
Change the SQL and/or reduce the data field sizes and/or number of fields being returned and resubmit the
request. Limit the projection list and order by clause to approximately 64k bytes of data each.